# Dynamic Json Response mapping to Pojo using GSON

Tags: java, json, dynamic, gson

I have an Issue that i have to create a JAVA program to Call a Rest service and Map the output json to the Pojo using GSON. But the problem is json response of the Rest service i am calling is Dynamic. Now what should i do? can anyone help

Comment: Please provide some code and/or a good description of the possible forms of the json response. What makes the difference? Amount of entries or just the type?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please read [ask]

Comment: Add some code and your API response.